# Pepper: return to the start of the program if there is not interaction

Tags: pepper, choregraphe

I'm making a Pepper app with Choregraphe and I have a doubt:
Pepper has to maintain a conversation with a human user and the problem is that if the user "disappears", the app is in middle of an state, and if it doesn't get any interaction, it should got to the first state (return to the start of the program). The idea was to use a timeout of no response (like the timeout between machines). Is there a way to do this with Choregraphe?

PD: The project is big and there are a lot of boxes, so add a timeout box and link it to all boxes can be messy.

PD: I have been looking to make a [trigger condition](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-4/naoqi/interaction/triggerconditions.html), but in the condition it should detect tablet interactions like touch or that user talk to the robot.

Answer (score 1):

A good way is to put all the "lot of boxes" into a parent-box (new box/diagram box).

Thus when you time out, you just stop the parent box, and all the inner box will be stopped automatically.